# How to keep track of slightly differing codebases in a single git repository

Tags: git

We run multiple webshops for multiple languages, and want to version them with git. The differ only slighly - some lines of css, a different php file, an additional image. Alltogether 98% is the same among all languages, so a single repository would be great. How can we achieve this?

Here are my ideas:

- In CSS, the body tag gets a class "lang-en" or "lang-fr", so selectors can be language specific.
- For language files, .gitignore on the target system can do a great job.
- For configuration, the main and .gitignored file can contain the language.

But how about slight changes in 3rd-party-php-code? Is there a way to tell git what part of a file to check out? Something like

```
aaaaa
---GIT CHECKOUT IF LANG=EN---
bbb
---GIT ENDIF---
ccc
```

Sorry for the incorrect naming, butI don´t even know how to call what I want.

Regards

EDIT: Just an idea: the language-neutral version as main repository, and the differences as git submodules. Could that work?

Comment: Personally, I think you're trying to use the wrong tool for the job. VCS's are used to keep a history of versions of the same product, not multiple similar products.

Comment: Thanks, dcastro. The sites used to run the exactly same code (the system allows localization via database), but with time little differences grew. However, it still is considered the same code. So you might be right, but we still hope for a simple solution. :)